# <a> element with class not taking its class CSS properties

Tags: html, css

Why is it that  elements with classes are not taking their respective class (.1stBtn and .2ndBtn) CSS properties in the following example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="heroContent">
                    
    <a class="1stBtn" href="classes.html">Button 1</a> 
                                
    <a class="2ndBtn" href="http://eepurl.com/VsOdX">Button 2</a>
                    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.heroContent a {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
        
.1stBtn {
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
        
.2ndBtn {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
        
.heroContent a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tej5esho/3/

Just to be clear, I'd expect the buttons' text color to be white and the .1stBtn background color to show green.

I've also tried to target those classes with, e.g.:

> .1stBtn
>
> a.1stBtn
>
> .heroContent a.1stBtn

None of the above are working.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Class name can't start with a number.

Comment: @Benio a practical example to support your argument would be great. an updated fiddle perhaps..?

Comment: @TJ Added example to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As emmanuel mentioned, class names cannot start with numbers.The rules are:
Naming rules:

- Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
  and underscores ("_")
- In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

Comment: Thanks for summarising the rules!

Answer (score 2):

## Clarification

According to spec, [`class`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes)

> Every HTML element may have a class attribute specified.
>
> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.
>
> **There are no additional restrictions** on the tokens authors can use in the class attribute

It means, class can begin with numbers.

## Source of the problem

While `HTML` allows to use any `classname`, `CSS` still lack of `HTML5` and you can`t use the short rule (beggining with a `.`) yet.

## Solution

Use `[class="1stBtn"]` instead of `.1stBtn`.

## Example

Here is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tej5esho/8/) with corrected `CSS` rules.

Comment: @Benio I didn't downvote, but *"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional** and enthusiast programmers"*. Your behaviour can have an impact on voting because as far as I know members are free to vote as per their wish.

Comment: Thanks for explaining workaround to the limitation identified in issue.

Answer (score 2):

By CSS syntax rules, a CSS identifier cannot being with an unescaped digit. Therefore, a selector like .1stBtn-8 is invalid. But the digit can be escaped, by [CSS escaping rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#escaping): the selector

```
.\31 stBtn-8
```

or, equivalently,

```
.\000031stBtn-8
```

is valid and matches an element with class=1stBtn-8.

Needless to say, class names starting with a digit are best avoided, but if you have to work with them (e.g., because some HTML documents have them and you cannot change the markup), this is the way.

Comment: Thanks for explaining workaround to the limitation identified in issue.